# DynamoDB Conditional SaveAsync

Tags: c#, amazon-dynamodb

I'm using the following code:

```
DynamoDBContextConfig config = new DynamoDBContextConfig()
{
    ConsistentRead = false,
    Conversion =  DynamoDBEntryConversion.V2
};

using (DynamoDBContext context = new DynamoDBContext(config))
{
    long unixTimestamp = (long)(DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract(new DateTime(1970, 1, 1))).TotalSeconds;
    QTrackStatus qTrackStatus = new QTrackStatus()
    {
        Key = "m@m.com",
        EventCode = "CC",
        EventDateTime = "2019-09-09 14:00:30",
        EventLocation = "BFS",
        EventLastUpdate = unixTimestamp
    };

    DynamoDBOperationConfig dynamoDBOperationConfig = new DynamoDBOperationConfig()
    {
        QueryFilter = new List<ScanCondition>()
        {
            { new ScanCondition("EventCode", ScanOperator.NotEqual, "CC") }
        },
        ConditionalOperator = ConditionalOperatorValues.And
    };

    await context.SaveAsync(qTrackStatus, dynamoDBOperationConfig);
}
```

What I'm trying to do is only save the record if the EventCode is not CC.  Currently it's always saving.  I could retrieve the record first, do a check and then call SaveAsync if required - however I'd like to do it all in the SaveAsync call.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Unless I've missed something, it doesn't look like this is possible with the higher level api.  I ended up re-factoring to the following:

```
AmazonDynamoDBClient client = new AmazonDynamoDBClient();

UpdateItemRequest updateItemRequest = new UpdateItemRequest()
{
    TableName = "QTrackStatus",
    ReturnValues = ReturnValue.ALL_NEW,
    ConditionExpression = "EventCode <> :ec",
    UpdateExpression = "SET EventCode = :ec, EventDateTime = :edt, EventLocation = :el, EventLastUpdate = :elu",
    ExpressionAttributeValues = new Dictionary<string, AttributeValue>()
    {
        { ":ec", new AttributeValue("CC") },
        { ":edt", new AttributeValue("2019-09-09 14:00:30") },
        { ":el", new AttributeValue("BFS") },
        { ":elu", new AttributeValue() { N = ((long)(DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract(new DateTime(1970, 1, 1))).TotalSeconds).ToString() } }
    },
    Key = new Dictionary<string, AttributeValue>()
    {
        { "Key", new AttributeValue("m@m.com") }
    }
};

try
{
    UpdateItemResponse updateItemResponse = await client.UpdateItemAsync(updateItemRequest);
}
catch(ConditionalCheckFailedException e)
{

}
```

This allows me to achieve my goal.